# NSViewRepresentable is crashing Binding to SwiftData?

Tags: swiftui, swift-data, nsviewrepresentable

I am trying to create Markdown in TextEditor using NSViewRepresentable, it is working fine, but the binding from NSViewRepresentable seems to confuse SwiftData. It will update properly until I select one item on the list, after that everything I write will be updated on the first item I clicked, even after selecting other item on the list. This won't happen if I link to default TextEditor view. Am I doing something wrong, or it's a bug?

Here is the "Content View":

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(sort: \Entry.timestamp, order: .reverse, animation: .default) private var entries: [Entry] 
    
    @State var selection: Entry? = nil 
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(entries) { entry in
                    @Bindable var bindableEntry = entry
                    NavigationLink {
                        RichTextEditor(text: $bindableEntry.text)
                    } label: {
                        ListItemView(entry: entry, isFavorite: $bindableEntry.isFavorite)
                            .keyboardShortcut(.delete, modifiers: [])
                            .onDeleteCommand(perform: {
                                delete(entry)
                            })....
}
```

And here is the NSViewRepresentable:

```
struct RichTextEditor: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSScrollView {
        let scrollView = MyTextView.scrollableTextView()
        let textView = scrollView.documentView as! MyTextView
        
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSScrollView, context: Context) {
        let textView = nsView.documentView as! MyTextView
        let selectedRanges = textView.selectedRanges
        textView.string = text
        textView.selectedRanges = selectedRanges
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextViewDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            if let textView = notification.object as? MyTextView {
               print("textDidChange")
                
                let selectedRanges = textView.selectedRanges
                text = textView.string
                
                textView.selectedRanges = selectedRanges
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is wrapped on a NSScrollView because it NSTextView doesn't have scroll, but the same thing happens if I use a NSTextView.

I think is something related to the `text = textView.string` in "textDidChange" on "Coordinator", I think it's strange that I have to set the value of a binding property, but it won't save it in swift data if I don't do it and I don't know how I could make it different.

Comment: Your call
 `RichTextEditor(text: $bindableEntry.text, inFocus: $focusedView)`
 does not match your `init(text: Binding<String>, fontSize: Binding<Double>) { _text = text }`.
 There is no `inFocus` declaration but there is a `@Binding private var fontSize: Double`.
You should also initialise the `inFocus` or `fontSize` in the `init()`.
Is the code you are showing us really the code that produces your crash?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not related. I just removed part of the code because it is too big. I just forget to remove some parts. Nothing of it is related to the problem, I know because I removed everything to try to find the culprit. It's either the way I implement NSViewRepresentable or a problem with SwiftData or Binding.

Comment: AFAIK, to change the `content` of one of your Query `[Entry]`,
 you need to use/update the `context`, not through using a binding.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that, but I can say that using plain TextEditor view in navigationLink everything works perfectly. Binding updates all the model in real time. But when I try to use a custom TextView, it starts to update the textView to the first item that I clicked after running the app. Always the same strange behavior. My suspicion is that I am doing some mistakes in the implementation of NSViewRepresentable. Or maybe @Bindable doesn't work with NSViewRepresentable.

Comment: In core data, for sure, I had to implement an update method. But I don't know if it is possible in this arrangement.

Comment: Yes, ok. I replaced `MyTextView` with `NSTextView` and all works well for me in my tests.
Have to go now, a strong earthquake here in Japan.

Comment: Hope you are safe

Comment: @lorem ipsum, all good here, thank you for asking. I'm in Tokyo, on the other side of the quake hit region, 
and yet my building shook strongly and swayed for quite some times afterwards.
I'm on the 32 floor, and the noise inside the apartment is like a old wooden ship creaking, very scary.